# c++, how bit shifting by n works

Tags: c, bit

I'm wondering how bit shifting works. For example, if we do `i>>3`, does it shift `i` to the right three times (i.e.  `i=i>>1;` `i=i>>1;` `i=i>>1`) or does it change each bits' positions by three at once (i.e. `x[a+3]` for all bit positions)?

Comment: It depends on the architecture and the commands for bit shifting that the architecture has. The compiler will try to do as efficiently as possible with the given set of commands. So for which architecture are you asking?

Comment: The `SHR` and `SHL` are operators which shift bits to right and left.

Comment: Seems to me the answer could be "all at once, for any modern architecture". Is there any modern architecture which doesn't have a barrel shifter in it? In other words, O(1) speed instead of order O(n) speed (where n is shift size).

Comment: @Dithermaster Many embedded processors   lack a barrel shifter.

Comment: Thanks @chux, didn't know that. I suppose every transistor matters. Ironically, it's embedded processors that do more bit twiddling.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specified by the language and hence implementation dependent. The compiler will generally implement the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

How a compiler generates code for a bit shift operation depends on the target
architecture and the optimization level of the compiler. Different architectures have different opcodes for shifting.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0xaa;

    i = i >> 3;

    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Look at the different [assembly outputs](https://godbolt.org/g/zcZaVo) from GNU GCC 7.2 x86_64 with different
optimization levels: only for `-O0` the compiler uses an opcode for bit shift:

```
sar DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 3
```

for all other optimization levels, the compiler stores the value `0x15` directly
into `edi`.

Not let's change the code a little bit:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = argc;

    i = i >> 3;

    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Now suddenly [all optimization](https://godbolt.org/g/31VPBL) are using the `sar` opcode to do calculate
the bit shift.

As you can see, there is no definitive answer to that, other than compilers are
very clever and will try to use the most efficiant way of doing stuff, and
sometimes not doing them is "better". Play with different compilers on the
godbolt.org links I provided to see the different ways different compiler
versions deal with it. If you change on godbolt.org compiler explorer the language to C++,
you can even compile it for different architectures like [arm and mips](https://godbolt.org/g/D39cRK).